# Lower and Upper confidence limit on estimated arithmetic mean using Land's exact procedure

Tags: confidence-interval, lognormal-distribution

I have to compute the LCL95% and UCL95% using Land's "exact" method. I computed the LCL and UCL for this lognormal distribution using another technique and I can't find anything for Land's exact procedure.

My data set `x = {0.043, 0.236, 0.057, 0.016}`

Here is what I tried

$y =$ mean of $\ln{x}$

$s^2 =$ standard deviation of $\ln x$.

Confidence limits $ = \exp\left(y + s^2/2 \pm z\sqrt{s^2/n + s^4/2(n-1)}\right)$

and I got UCL: 2.98 and LCL: 0.139
but the answer using Land's exact is UCL95%:11.6 and LCL95%: 0.039

Here is what I have calculated already:

- Mean: 0.088
- Standard deviation: 0.1
- Geometric mean: 0.0552
- Geometric standard deviation: 3.04
- Estimated arithmetic mean using MVUE: 0.085
- 95th percentile: 0.343
- Upper limit of tolerance: 16.8
- mean of $\ln{x} = -2.898$
- standard deviation of $\ln{x} = 1.112$

Can anyone please help me sketch out an algorithm for the formula when using Land's exact method?

Comment: (i) when you say "I couldn't find anything" what did you try?  (ii) When you say "I have to" ... from where does this compulsion arise? Is this for a class, say?

Comment: @Glen_b No I am doing this for work, its for Industrial Hygiene where I am replacing some functions from an excel sheet into an asp.net webapp and I tried to find everything I could for Lands exact but I haven't found much. Most of the readings ive done only talk about the 'regular' way of calculating the confidence limits but according to AIHA we use Lands exact for computing LCLs and UCLs for IH.

Also I don't need the answer, im just looking for the right formula and how Land's exact method differs from what I tried above

Comment: If you're converting *from* an excel spreadsheet, you have a spreadsheet formula, do you not?  The procedure is found in
Land, C. E. (1988),  
Hypothesis tests and interval estimates,  
In *Lognormal Distribution*, (Crow and Shimizu eds),  
New York: Marcel Dekker,  pp 87-112  
... but I am not sure you'll find it enlightening, since it takes about three pages to do it (p103-106) and it seems to assume you have tables that are in other documents. There's also R code for it [here](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/esh/aoed/ORNLTM2005-52.pdf) (see p 40)

Comment: @Glen_b No i cant trace the formula completely from excel, im not very skilled in excel. I will look at the document you sent and if i can figure it out i will post my answer here. Thanks!

Comment: @Glen_b Here is an example of the issue im having, the document Lognormal Distribution, (Crow and Shimizu eds), New York: Marcel Dekker is a paid book and its expensive. I found the procedure for Land's exact but i am stuck on getting the C-factor for the 95% LCL and 95% UCL. Would you know where i can find this table? :)

Comment: The table is on my Web site (as an Excel workbook) linkable through http://www.quantdec.com/envstats/software/.

Comment: @whuber Thanks Whuber, as an example, my sample count is 4, mean-logs is -2.898, Sy = 1.112 and for the UCL, im stuck with which value to take since it has values for n=3 and n=5 and the values for UCL vary a lot. For Sy ~ 1.00, n=3, H factor is 13.05 and when n=5 H factor is 4.905 so what would you recommend for n=4, should i average the Hfactors for n=3 and n=5 to 8.977?

Comment: Averaging is not a good idea. Gilbert quotes Land in recommending that cubic interpolation in these tables should be adequate.  A link on the web page I referenced ("Perform linear, quadratic, cubic, etc. interpolation (used to interpolate Land's H factor tables)") will send you to a spreadsheet showing how to do that. With a sample count of $4$ the results are heavily dependent on the assumption of lognormality, so you have much more serious issues to deal with in evaluating the sensitivity to that assumption.

Comment: I_shoot_photos -- I don't have the book either. Google books showed me the relevant section quite happily. If you're in the US you'll probably find it shows you more than it shows me; for some reason it often seems to be the case. I found the book simply by searching on terms in your question and then searching for references in those hits.

Comment: @whuber, in the example data above, my LCL95% matched and i got 0.0387 but my UCL didnt match 
I interpolated the values for LCL i got when n=4, H factor is -1.533 which when plugged into the equation works.
But when i do the same itnerpolation to find values when Sy = 1.112 and interpolate again using the points n=3,5,7,10 i get the H factor to be 8.6109 but when plugged into the equation it gives me a UCL of 25.74 which is way above what it is supposed to be (11.6) would you know where i am going wrong?


Sy = 1.112
n=3 -> 14.51
n=5 -> 5.396
n=7 -> 4.019
n=10 -> 3.337


Final value = 8.6109

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be $11.6$?  Perhaps that value is a mistake.

Comment: @whuber nope im pretty sure its correct as the excel sheet im using comes from AIHA (its called EASC-IHSTATS v229) and the value is confirmed to be correct. What i found out is that for a larger sample size like 22, even after interpolation the LCL and UCL using the same formula turns out to be correct. Maybe just for small values of n it does this anomaly?

Comment: Perhaps it is interpolating differently--but that's a pretty big difference. (The implied value of $H$ they are using is more than $1$ less than you are computing.)  Because that workbook does not allow you to view the formulas or the macros, it cannot be considered authoritative or trustworthy.

Comment: That's a good point whuber thanks a lot for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This report](http://www.epa.gov/oswer/riskassessment/pdf/ucl.pdf) describes the Land Method on page 10.

[image: page 10]

The values for step 3 in [Gilbert's Paper](http://www.osti.gov/scitech/biblio/7037501)

Comment: This is the original paper of Land:  https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177693235

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a statistical software implementation of Land's Exact method then in R this is provided by the `EnvStats` package available on CRAN.

The `elnormAlt()` function from this package can be used to calculate Land's confidence interval as well as other (Zou *et al* and Parkin *et al* and Cox) methods of confidence intervals for the lognormal distribution.

Comment: Although implementation is often mixed with substantive content in questions,
we are supposed to be a site for providing information about statistics, machine
learning, etc., not code. It can be good to provide code as well, but please
elaborate your substantive answer in text for people who don't read this language
well enough to recognize & extract the answer from the code.