# reference table for Lower and Upper confidence limit on estimated arithmetic mean using Land's exact procedure

Tags: confidence-interval, mean

is there a reference table (gilbert table) that allows for samples greater than 101? @whuber posted a link to the website quantdec.com/envstats/software. – whuber♦ Jul 23 '14 at 15:47 that was extremely useful but wanted to clarify where the infinity column came from and whether it is sound to use this look up table for samples greater than 101. if not what would you recommend?

Comment: The question referred to by this one is here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108909/lower-and-upper-confidence-limit-on-estimated-arithmetic-mean-using-lands-exact

Comment: You should be able to find the answer [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177693235)  --- original paper by Land